# Can't receive sms with twilio

Tags: twilio

maybe somebody know and describe to me - why a month ago I use twilio & receive sms, but know stopped? I'm use http://twimlbin.com and put the same code 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Record/>
</Response>`
But sms didn't came to me more?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

The code you have here will not send an SMS message, it will try to record a voice call instead.

To send SMS replies you need this [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
    <Message>Your message here</Message>
</Response>
```

Put that into your TwiMLbin snippet, connect the URL to the *Messaging Request URL* in your twilio number, and send it an SMS message.

Let me know if you have any further issues.